# Trying to install OpenVPN and can't find the Vpn Configuration in task bar

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

I installed openvpn Ubuntu GNOME and I cannot find the VPN tab for further configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```